# Call command in docker container from other docker container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I'm relatively new to docker and trying to set up a simple PHP project with docker-compose.

I use the `php:8.1-fpm` container and the `composer:2.3.9` container images to start from.

My docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  my-php-fpm:
    container_name: my-php-fpm
    build:
      context: .docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - my-composer

  my-composer:
    container_name: my-composer
    build:
      context: .docker/composer
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

The composer/Dockerfile:

```
FROM composer:2.3.9

CMD ["composer", "install"]
```

The php-fpm/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libssl-dev zlib1g-dev curl git unzip \
    netcat libxml2-dev libpq-dev libzip-dev openssh-client && \
    pecl install apcu && \
    pecl install xdebug && \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) bcmath intl opcache zip && \
    docker-php-ext-enable apcu sodium && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

When building, the composer container downloads a composer and right after buildig it executes it `CMD ["composer", "install"]` but this fails because some extensions are missing.

Now I want to execute the composer command of the composer container from the php-fpm container, because the php-fpm container has some more extensions installed and I don't want to install all these extensions in both containers.

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: A container can never directly invoke a command in another; similarly, a Dockerfile can't run something that only exists in another image.  The linked question has several recipes for installing Composer as part of a PHP-based image, which would let you `RUN composer install` as part of your image build sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.